# Как с помощью SED удалить предпоследнее слово в строке?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Есть допустим файл и в нем строка - qwerty qwerty2 qwert3 qwert4 
Как с помощью команды sed удалить предпоследнее слово?

Comment: так: `s/qwert3//`

Comment: а если я не буду знать какое именно слово нужно?Просто, предпоследнее, так возможно?

Comment: `/это-удаляем(это-сохраняем)/\1/`

Comment: не совсем понял 
s//\1/ ?

Comment: видимо, настало время наконец прочесть [документацию](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/)

Comment: ладно, спасибо))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подразумевая, что слова разделяются пробельными символами и используется GNU sed, как-то так:

```
sed -re 's!\S+\s+(\S+\s*)$!\1!'
```

Идея в том, что для замены выбираются два последних слова и вся эта строка заменяется только на последнее. Слово подразумевается как любое количество не-пробелов (\S+) завершаемое одним или несколькими пробелами (\s+)

Comment: То, что было нужно. Заработало! Спасибо, там реально нужно было регулярный.

Answer (score 2):

Привет,

Интересный вопрос, решил через **awk**.  С **sed** будет громозко и у него нет удобной поддержки строк или полей.

```
~$ cat test.me 
hello world, I am here
hello world, I am here
hello world, I am here
hello world, I am here
hello world, I am here

~$ awk 'NF>1{$(NF-1)=""};1' test.me 
hello world, I  here
hello world, I  here
hello world, I  here
hello world, I  here
hello world, I  here
```

**Пояснения**

- **NF**: *Number of Fields in a record*

Число полей (столбцов в строке)

- **NF>1**

Пропускать пустые строки

- **$(NF-1)=""**

Прировнять 2е с конца поле пустому значению.

Если нужно обновить файл:

```
~$ awk 'NF>1{$(NF-1)=""};1' test.me > test.me_tmp && mv test.me_tmp test.me
```

**Ссылки**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215958/how-can-i-delete-the-5th-word-of-every-line-in-a-file
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005627/nth-word-in-a-string
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web

Comment: С awk я уже делал. И теперь я уверен, что делал правильно. Но тут именно нужно было с SED. Спасибо